# Installing new rolls on existing Rocks Cluster

Tags: cluster, hpc

I am on a supercomputer research team at a small university. We can't seem to find where the CUDA roll is installed on our Rocks cluster, and we're pretty sure it was never properly installed. We do have the iso of the roll. In searching on how to reinstall a roll, the only method of installing a single new roll that my colleagues is to create a restore roll and reinstall the frontend with the restore roll and any new rolls. Is there some better way that we're missing? The cluster we have cannot be taken down for an extended period, as a class needs it for ongoing assignments.

Comment: +1 for working on a SuperComputer and coming to SuperUser for an answer.

Comment: ^ I don't get it... was that a joke? How does one decide whether a question belongs in Server Fault vs. Super User??

Comment: @KaitlynMcmordie Simple: read the FAQ. There are dozens of Stack Exchange sites, and each is dedicated to specific questions. "Power User" questions wind up here; "System Administrator" questions go to ServerFault.